# Why does Javascript change the 0111 number parameter to 73

Tags: javascript

I guess this has something to do with binary numbers but I have not been able to find anything explaining why, most likely because I don't know what to search for. I have the following code. I pass in a number parameter of 0111 and inside the function body it logs the number 73. Im just trying to learn why. Linked resources with explanation would be nice. Thanks.

```
function whatTheHecksGoingOn(num) {
    console.log(num)
}

whatTheHecksGoingOn(0111);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numericl literals beginning with `0` in JavaScript are interpreted as being in Octal notation. 0111 in Octal is equivalent to 73.

Comment: It's octal, not hex. `0x` is the hex prefix

Comment: Already corrected, mb. I posted this answer right before the question was closed, woops.